# rails 3 pagination with kaminari on mongoid embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, kaminari

When I call paginate with kaminari on a collection of embedded documents I get the following error:

```
(Access to the collection for Document is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root document.):
```

Any idea on how I can fix that ? I have installed kaminari as a gem.

Alex

Comment: what is mongoid version do you have?

Comment: Not relevant to embedded programming.  Retagged.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to access the collection through the parent object. For example, given the following models:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :bookmarks
end

class Bookmark
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
end
```

Then to paginate a given user's bookmarks you would do:

```
@user.bookmarks.page(params[:page])
```

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work for me: undefined local variable or method `page' for #<#<Class:0x10e383ba0>:0x10e37fe88>, my models is "Document" embedded in "Project"

Comment: Weird. I tested this on a project I'm working on right now - and it definitely works. Looks like you might have some other issues going on though, since it appears to be calling `Page` on a `Class` - not your collection `Criteria`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue on Kaminari: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/89

So I forked it, and fixed it following the solution provided by spatrik. I am not 100% sure it will work on all cases and that this solution does not have any drawbacks. But for the moment it works exactly as expected.

Alex

Answer (score 1):

I just sent a patch for the issue. Take a look at the request. hope this helps solve your issue.
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/pull/155/files

Answer (score 0):

With the previous theTRON example :

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :bookmarks
end

class Bookmark
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :created_at, :type => DateTime

  embedded_in :user
end
```

the following, will get you the error you described in your post :

```
@user.bookmarks.desc(:created_at).page(params[:page])
```

while the nex one will works fine :

```
@user.bookmarks.page(params[:page]).desc(:created_at)
```

I hope it help.